# Connect lan printer to wlan on seperate networks

Tags: networking, router, printer, dd-wrt

We have two modems in our offices providing two different internet connections. One modem is linked to an ethernet switch which connects 10 PCs and a printer together. The other Modem is connected to a router providing wireless. All of the hardware is relatively next to each other, and the router has 4 open ethernet ports. Is there a way to connect the router to the switch, while preserving the separate ISP connections, so that I can use the printer over wireless too? The LAN IP is currently 10.10.10.XXX while the WLAN IP is on 192.168.XXX.XXX. I have DD-WRT installed on the router. Is this possible?